# How to get alexa to continue speaking until user intervention

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop a skill where alexa continues to speak until stopped. Say I have an array of items that I want alexa to cycle through and speak.

So far I have only managed to wait for a reprompt / end session where I call on Amazon.NextIntent to move on to the next item in the list, however that requires user to keep saying next..next..

Any ideas/tips on how I can achieve this? I am using a self hosted service.

Comment: Maybe you can loop through your list creating the phrase appending items to a string and then prompt that string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all speak as much as you can and concatenate your items text from the array.
You can use 8000 characters.

> The outputSpeech response cannot exceed 8000 characters ([source](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html))

So depending on the text size of your items, response with these items and record the index at which item you want to continue (e.g. save as session attribute).
At the end of every turn your should have a question like "you want to listen to more items? Than you can react on the YES.Intent and continue with your saved item index and fill up the 8000 characters again.